# Position of Content with Trackpad Scroll

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I am using jscrollpane and am wondering how to determine where the content is when a user uses a mac magic mouse or trackpad and scrolls horizontally within a div.

I have tried the following:

```
$('.cal-slider').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert(slider_api.getContentPositionX());
});
```

However this appears to only trigger when the user uses the mousewheel up or down.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind to the [jQuery scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event instead.  This event will be fired when the user scrolls in a pane.